# Display up to 3 rows of a text field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ellipsis

**Goal**: I'd like to display up to 3 lines of a long text field in a `<div>` of defined width.

**Current flawed approach**:

```
<style>
  div{ 
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    white-space:normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow:ellipsis;
  }
</style>


<div>
  <%= @company.description %>
</div>
```

**Problem**: The above cuts off the bottom line if it is not perfectly lined up with the arbitrary 100px+20px height. So, I often end up with a line of text halfway cut off horizontally. How can I instead display up to 3 **whole** lines of text instead of cutting it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `em`, not `px` for the `height`. So something like `3em` or `3.12em` to get it just right (cater for the padding as well).

Comment: I have this `div` inside a bigger one measured in pixels. I'm afraid of having this small one overrun the bigger one if I use `em`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I just changed the height to `em`. Is there a way to preserve the ellipsis if the text is still longer than 3 lines?